# postgresql rename multiple substrings in a json string with one query

Tags: string, postgresql, performance, replace

I want to save update requests. So instead of doing this:

```
update table set column = REPLACE(column,'abc','xyz');
update table set column = REPLACE(column,'def','uvw');
...
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
UPDATE table
SET column =
CASE
    WHEN column like '%"abc":%' THEN REPLACE(column,'"abc":','"xyz":')
    WHEN column like '%"def":%' THEN REPLACE(column,'"def":','"uvw":')
    ...
END
WHERE COLUMN2 = 'something';
```

But this is not doing the kind of loop I need. It replaces only the first match it finds.

I know I can also do something like this:

```
update table
set column = REPLACE(REPLACE(column,'abc','xyz'),'def','uvw')
where COLUMN = 'something';
```

But I don't know about the performance of each of them.

Comment: Nesting replace statements looks like a fine solution for your problem IMHO.

Comment: Regarding your statement with the CASE, does/can `column` contain both "abc" and "def"? If so then yes the statement with the multiple REPLACE commands is the way to go.

Comment: the json string contains "abc" and "def". But with the nested replacement and about 10 strings, it looks confusing. I thought I could do better.

Comment: Well the reason why the CASE statement doesn't work correctly is because only one of the CASE paths will be executed; if `column like '%"abc":%'` then it will perform the first replace, and that will be the end of that CASE statement evaluation for that field, it won't go on to also check if it contains "def" etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try different formatting for nested replaces:

```
update table
set column =    REPLACE(
                REPLACE(
                REPLACE(
                REPLACE(column, 'abc','xyz'),
                                'def','uvw'),
                                'zxc','acv'),
                                'xcv','bvn')
where COLUMN = 'something';
```